# Go back to previous page without execute body onload

Tags: javascript, html

is there any way I can do 
`window.history.go(-1);`in javascript without execute

init function in body onload

```
<body onload="init()">
```

Or how to set a parameter in this function

```
`window.history.go(-1);`
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: as soon the page loads you want to go back one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried window.history.back()?